# Dont see the options and cant select

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a little box, where I can change language, but it's not working. I don't see any mistake. When I click on this box it does not open, and I can't choose the option. But why?

What I want to do? I want to do something like this: If u choose option->EST then its going to index.html and if u choose option->ENG then its going to index_eng.html

In HTML I have:

```
<nav id="menu4">
    <select>
       <option href="index.html" value="est">EST</option>
       <option href="index_eng.html" value="eng">ENG</option>
    </select>
</nav>
```

In CSS I have:

```
#menu4 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}

#menu4 ul {
    text-align: right;
}

#menu4 a {
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'futura_bk_btbook';
}

#menu4 .selected a {
    /*text-decoration: underline;*/
}
```

And also I have script for this dropdown menu:

```
$('option').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    window.location = url;
});
```

Comment: `click` on `<option>` is not commonly supported.

Comment: you can't bind events to an option tag, IE is one browser that won't register them. Use change handler on select instead

Comment: But how I can bind events then ?

Comment: also an option doesn't have `href`

Comment: `option` elements don't have an `href` attribute. If you want to put arbitrary information on elements, use [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this

```
<select name="menu4" onchange="window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
 <option value="index.html">EST</option>
 <option value="index_eng.html">ENG</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This looks nice, but why its not opening in my page ? If I try it in wamp, its working but if I try it just `file:///C:/Users/Erki/Desktop/asdasdasd/homepage/index.html` then this select is not opening.

Comment: I guess its not allowed to load local resource from javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `.change(function() {...});` to do this.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rexygumy/) is the demo.

```
$("select").change(function(){
var url = $(this).children('option').attr('href');
window.location = url;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to us `change` on the select, and then get the `href` of the relevant `option`.

```
$('select').on('change',function() {
    var href = $(this).children('option:selected').attr('href');
    if (href) {
        window.location = href;
    }
});
```

Also, note that `option` elements don't have an `href` attribute. If you want to put arbitrary information on elements, use [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).

Example (making both changes):

```js
$('select').on('change',function() {
  var href = $(this).children('option:selected').attr('data-href');
  if (href) {
    alert("Changed: " + href);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option data-href="index.html" value="est">EST</option>
  <option data-href="index_eng.html" value="eng">ENG</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this.

```
<nav id="menu4">
    <select id="swt_lng">
       <option value="#" >Language</option>     
       <option value="index.html" >EST</option>
       <option value="index_eng.html" >ENG</option>
    </select>
</nav>

$('#swt_lng').change(function(){
    var url = $(this).val();
    window.location = url;
});
```

or

```
<nav id="menu4">
        <select>
           <option value="#" >Language</option>
           <option value="index.html" >EST</option>
           <option value="index_eng.html" >ENG</option>
        </select>
    </nav>

    $('#menu4 select').change(function(){
        var url = $(this).val();
        window.location = url;
    });
```

Comment: As the select element does not have a value on its own – does this really work in jQuery?

Comment: @FarveenHassan Yes, it works. Read jQuery documentation for the same

Answer (score -2):

You chould bind the `change` event to the `SELECT` instead of the `OPTION` tags. Every time a new option is selected the `onchange` event will get triggered.

```
jQuery( 'select' ).on( 'change', function() {
    var url = jQuery( this.options[this.selectedIndex] ).attr( 'href' );
    window.location = url;
} );
```

Comment: yea, but this select is not opening, why ?